# Extract price/cost only once

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to extract the price from any of the following:

```
Item price: £93.00 Item number: 265722305071

Item number: 265722305071 Item price: $93.00 

£93.00£93.00
 
265722305071£93.00 foo

265722305071-93.00EURO
```

Target response: 93.00

These are a selection of my attempts:

```
/^(\d*([.,](?=\d{3}))?\d+)+((?!\2)[.,]\d\d)?$/

/^£?[1-9]{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?$/

/^£?(([1-9]{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?)|(0\.[1-9]\d)|(0\.0[1-9]))$/

/^\xA3?\d{1,3}?([,]\d{3}|\d)*?([.]\d{1,2})?$/

/^\$?[0-9][0-9,]*[0-9]\.?[0-9]{0,2}$/i

(?=.*?\d)^\$?(([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)|\d+)?(\.\d{1,2})?$

/(?=.)^\$?(([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})*)|0)?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/

[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9](?:[^0-9a-zA-Z\s\S\D]|$)

^\d+\.\d{2}$
```

I'll use a separate regex to extract the currency.

The problem may lie in not knowing what regex engine is being used. The tool I'm using is n8n but I can't find what regex flavour it uses. Everything else is using Javascript which is where I started.

Comment: `([$£])([0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9])` I don't think you've fully stated the problem though. There are no defined lengths. You seem to want to allow commas...

Comment: @shawnt00 depending on localization, `€50000,12` ≈ `€50000.12`. Though in OP's case I think they were going more for a number like `€50,000.12`

Comment: What language or tool are you using?

Comment: @Rogue Yes, that's true and essentially all part of the same question.

Comment: @MikeM - thanks for your help. So far the data I have has always been preceded by £ or $ but I suspect that I may have EUR in the future so to future-proof, I included the input data above but with the 'EUR' at the end, as I believe that's how it's written. So basically preceded by £ or $ or € in addition to end with EUR. Hope that makes sense and thanks again!

Comment: Apologies, I'm guessing you must be referring to something beyond the paragraph I originally wrote when I first posted but I'm not entirely sure how to find out any more useful information beyond what I initially wrote. I'm happy to contact the tools developers, n8n, to confirm it is actually the JavaScript flavour as initially stated, if that's what's being requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://regex101.com/r/NIPOfe/1) regex

```
(?:[$£])(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

This regex will capture all float and integer numbers that start either with the `$` or `£` sign.

##### Regex Explanation

- `(?:` Non-capturing group

  - `[$£]` Match either `$` or `£` sign
- `)` Close non-capturing group
- `(` Capturing group

  - `\d+` Match one or more digits
  - `(?:` Non-capturing group

    - `\.\d+` Match one or more digits with a `.` (dot) prefix
  - `)` Close non-capturing group
  - `?` The previous group can exist or not
- `)` Close group

##### *Edit Note*

As you mentioned below, a string can be followed by  `EUR` or `€` or even start with these components. So you can use [`(?<=[$£€]|EUR\s?)\d+\.\d+|\d+\.\d+(?=[$£€]|\s?EUR)`](https://regex101.com/r/2Omuy8/1) for that.

```js
function extractPrice(string) {
  let match = string.match(/(?<=[$£€]|EUR\s?)\d+\.\d+|\d+\.\d+(?=[$£€]|\s?EUR)/);
  return match ? match[0] : match;
}

console.log(extractPrice("Item price: £93.00 Item number: 265722305071"));
console.log(extractPrice("Item number: 265722305071 Item price: $93.00"));
console.log(extractPrice("£93.00£93.00"));
console.log(extractPrice("265722305071£93.00 foo"));
console.log(extractPrice("265722305071EUR93.00"));
console.log(extractPrice("265722305071EUR 93.00"));
console.log(extractPrice("265722305071 93.00 EUR"));
console.log(extractPrice("265722305071 93.00€"));
```

Comment: this is very much appreciated. It was actually one of the first things I tried but bizarrely, even for an input of 'Item price: £93.00 Item number: 265722305071' it outputs '93.00,93.00' - which seems strange. I can't work out why it's outputting it twice.

Comment: @binvius, I've updated my answer and just noticed that you changed the last input string. If the regex should match that one as well then please use [this](https://regex101.com/r/KDOyJE/1) regex.

Comment: @Artyom Vancyan -  your help is very kind and deeply appreciated. As mentioned in my comment further up, the EUR input is because I'm sure they will come up in future data. I'm therefore trying to amend your working formula to output the 93.00 from foofoofoo93.00EURO - any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If strings do not contain other floating numbers but prices then you can also use [`\d+\.\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/29ft8X/1). So `extractPrice` will return `string.match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0]`

Comment: @ Artyom Vancyan -  thanks again. I discovered the EUR format is usually EUR followed by a space so am hoping /(?:[$|£|EUR])(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/ is correct as it appears to be working? Finally and just because you seem really kind and knowledgeable, do you have any thoughts on my comment in this sub-thread about why it is outputting the number twice? (I could always split on the comma but was just confused as to why it might be doing it?)

Comment: It should not return a match twice as we don't use `g` (global) flag. You could use [`/(?<=[$£])\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=EUR)/`](https://regex101.com/r/BHKeGI/1) which will match any numbers followed by `$` or `£`, and/or numbers that next to exist `EUR`.

Comment: @Artyom Vancyan - appologies, the latest one appears to have fixed the duplicate issue. After discovering the EUR can be at the beginning followed by a space, I tried editing toe regex to /(?<=[$|£|EUR])\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=EUR)/ and also /(?<=[$|£|EUR\s])\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=EUR)/ but the first one doesn't work at all and the second one picks up other numbers in the input. Would love your wisdom on how to get this to finally work. Match $# or £# or EUR # or # EUR or #€ (although the last one isn't too important.) You are haveing a huge impact on many people so very grateful!

Comment: Please check my edit. If it is what you need, please let me know and update the regex explanation.

Comment: Oh my, you've done it! You're an absolute star! Cannot thank you enough. Looks like I came pretty close a few times but you have given me the knowledge now that I hope to be able to pass on one day. 

With your teaching, I managed to give that other regex mentioned a go to try and extract just the $, £, € or EUR. It appears to work!

([$£€]|EUR\s*?|\*s?EUR)

It's still displaying the results twice though like that initial issue I had (i.e. $,$ or EUR,EUR)

If you didn't change the other formula to deal with the duplicate issue, it must be a problem with the tool right. Unless you did?

Comment: Sorry but I still cannot understand how. Could you please send a code example that returns it twice?

Comment: If you didn't do anything to the formula to address it when I first mentioned it, the fact it isn't doing it now and doesn't do it in regex tools, means it must be a bug in the tool (n8n.) It's not the end of the world as for my currency symbol one, I'm simply splitting it. (Your one is working excellent without a need to split.) Anyway, not sure how to present a code example as it's in the tool. If of any interest, the input is: Total: EUR 35.89 Order number: 04-06077-14317. The code is: {{$node["setMixes"].json["price-mix"].match(/([$£€]|EUR\s*?|\*s?EUR)/).toString()}} The output is: EUR,EUR

Comment: Then you can just upvote and accept my answer if it was helpful to you :)

Comment: All done and massive help once again for your kindness and perseverance - really appreciated! Hope you have a lovely weekend.